# JSON return value not correctly changing CSS background image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am currently building an HTML form with three dropdowns that change content on the screen when a dropdown is changed.
I am achieving this by calling an AJAX function when a dropdown box is changed. This then interacts with a PHP function, which in return queries a database and then returns results in a JSON array. WHen this data is returned, I create HTML from the returned array and then show this to the user on the screen.

I am having an issue with URL's being returned in the JSON array. For each result I create an anchor tag with an inline style which uses a returned URL for the background-image url. Here is an example below:

```
jQuery(data).each(function(key, caseStudy) {                        
    html += '<div class="items-row cols-1 row-' + key + ' row-fluid clearfix">';
        html += '<div class="span12">';
            html += '<div class="item column-1">';                                      
                html += '<a href="#" style="background-image:url(' + caseStudy.introImage + ');"></a>';
                html += '<a href="#" class="title">Aberystwyth University</a>';                                         
            html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
});
    jQuery(".case-studies").html(html);
}
```

I am looping through each result that is returned in the JSON array and building an anchor tag which uses a URL returned (caseStudy.introImage) to change the background image of the element with an inline stlye. 
This inline style does not seem to be displaying correctly. I don't even get the 'style=' attribute shown in the output HTML.
Does anyone know why this may be happening? I have included my jQuery and the PHP function so you can see the data being sent and received.
Thanks

AJAX Call:

```
jQuery(document).on("change", "#case-studies-filter-wrap form select", function() {
            var url = "index.php";
            jQuery.ajax({
                type      :   'post',
                dataType  :   'json',
                url       :   url,
                data      :   jQuery("#case-studies-filter-wrap form").serialize() + "&tmpl=barebones" + "&caseStudy=1",
                success   :   function(data) {
                    if(data) {
                        var html = "";
                        jQuery(data).each(function(key, caseStudy) {                        
                            html += '<div class="items-row cols-1 row-' + key + ' row-fluid clearfix">';
                                html += '<div class="span12">';
                                    html += '<div class="item column-1">';                                          
                                        html += '<a href="#" style="background-image:url(' + caseStudy.introImage + ');"></a>';
                                        html += '<a href="#" class="title">Aberystwyth University</a>';                                         
                                    html += '</div>';
                                html += '</div>';
                            html += '</div>';
                        });
                        jQuery(".case-studies").html(html);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP Function (I am only showing the return array being built as the DB queries are returning the correct data).

```
$results = $db->loadAssocList();

    foreach($results as $result) {
        $images = json_decode($result['images']);           
        $caseStudiesReturn[] = array(
            'id'           =>   $result['id'],
            'name'         =>   $result['title'],
            'introImage'   =>   JURI::base() . stripslashes($images->image_intro),
            'fullImage'    =>   JURI::base() . $images->image_fulltext,

        );
    }   

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($caseStudiesReturn);
```

Console log of returned data:

```
fullImage
"http://###############/images/case-studies/devon-cornwall-constabulary/images/Intro.jpg"

id
"45"

introImage
"http://isca0###############/images/case-studies/devon-cornwall-constabulary/cover/cover-image.jpg"

name
"Devon & Cornwall Constabulary"
```

And here is what the generated HTML looks like (incorrect):

```
<a cover-image.jpg");"="" cover="" devon-cornwall-constabulary="" case-studies="" images="" ~gvmulti="" #########.info="" http:="" style="background-image:url(" href="#"></a>
```

Also, this is the returned JSON data as it is received. Could the backslashes be causing an error?

```
[{"id":"45","name":"Devon & Cornwall Constabulary","introImage":"http:\/\/###########.info\/~gvmulti\/images\/case-studies\/devon-cornwall-constabulary\/cover\/cover-image.jpg","fullImage":"http:\/\/##########.info\/~gvmulti\/images\/case-studies\/devon-cornwall-constabulary\/images\/Intro.jpg"}]
```

Comment: Try to `console.log(data);` in your success function.  I believe the `json_encode` in your PHP will return your urls formatted incorrectly so you may have to handle that in your JS before you insert them into the DOM.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too. I will edit the question with a dump in the console.

Comment: It seems like a problem with quoting somewhere, but I don't see it.

Comment: I have never used Joomla, but looks like your issue is in the `JURI::base()` call.

Comment: The JURI::base() call is simply a function in the JURI parent class that returns the baseurl of the domain. I use it to make sure the URL for the image is correct, and after testing these, they are. It is not that function that is causing the problem.

Comment: it seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/BYGt3/6/. The only changes I made were to hard-code the JSON, since I can't call your API.

Comment: How strange. Could it be anything to do with these backslashes? introImage":"http:\/\/###########.info\/~gvmulti\/images\/case-studies\/devon-cornwall-constabulary\/cover\/cover-image.jpg

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this problem?  I have the same issue, in Chrome, Firefox and IE.